# Converting image file from attachment to Pdf file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I am trying to convert images from the attachment of .msg file and save into PdF file. However i get the error when i tried to read the image file for converting into PdF file. Here is the part of my code

```
if count_attachments > 0:
    for item in range(count_attachments):          
        attached = msg.Attachments.Item(item + 1)            
        extension = attached.filename.split(".")[-1]

        if extension == 'jpg' or extension == 'png':
            pp = PdfPages(newname)
            img_data = open(attached, 'rb').read()                
            pp.savefig(img_data)                
            pp.close()
```

Here is the error I got from the compiler

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "email-reader1.py", line 52, in <module>
img_data = open(attached, 'rb').read()
TypeError: Can't convert 'CDispatch' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:
`img_data = open(attached, 'rb').read()`

with:
`img_data = open(attached.filename, 'rb').read()`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the code but now get new error saying no file or directory found. However the file present in the attachment. Here is the error:

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Scan 2016-7-28 0009.jpg

Comment: Am I suppose to download the file first and then download? Can any one guide me please